# Inetmgr6.exe missing on Windows server 2022, SMTP relay still working

Tags: smtp, iis-6, windows-server-2022, e-mailrelay

4 months ago, I have in-place upgraded a 2K8R2 server to 2K22.
It had the SMTP relay function, and this feature is still working on Server 2022. (I did the export-import function to get the settings from and old metadata.xml)
NB : I have already been able to edit the SMTP relay settings such as IP allow/deny from the 2022 server.

Pb is: today, the inetmgr6.exe is simply missing in the "C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv" folder.
Even copying it from and old W2K12R2 does not work.
Tried some dll roaming around too with no success.

Anyone has seen this recently ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831568(v=ws.11)#smtp SMTP components have been marked as deprecated for a decade, so anything can happen to them (including removal).

Comment: Roles don't remove themselves or vanish. Someone removed it. Also why 2012 R2? Use another Windows Server 2022 system. Or simply reinstall the Role Feature and reconfigure it. Should take about 15 minutes.

Comment: I know roles don't vanish but as this one is deprecated i thought MS would slowly remove parts. I took 2012R2 files from a running smtp relay server in case they were completely disabled on W2K22

Answer (score 0):

I finally disabled the IIS 6 Manager in "add/remove feature" (it was still enalbed thus not seeing the app in inetsrv folder)
after reboot, i re-enabled the feature and i found back my inetmgr6.exe.

not sure what has gone wrong, but it's back now.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing (7/9/2023) you can still get it to reinstall on Windows Server 2022 by using DSM provisioning.  From an elevated command prompt:

dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-LegacySnapIn

The idea that Microsoft could sell a server operating system that includes email, and then back-door break it trying to force us all to use their Office 365 spyware ....  and then they wonder why there is so much hostility to litigate and regulate their company ....